# What is the right syntax to describe multiple CSS styles only when they're inside a definite style?

Tags: html, css, nested

I'm trying to define some CSS rules only for pages of a definite type.

What is the right syntax to describe multiple css styles only when they're inside a definite style?

I know it works this way:

```
.service-page h1 {
        color: red;
    }

.service-page .style1 {
        color: blue;
    }

.service-page .style2 {
        color: pink;
    }
```

But I want something like this syntax I've tried. It also works, but not for all browsers, in particular, for iOS Chrome or Safari:

```
.service-page {

    h1 {
        color: red;
    }

    .style1 {
        color: blue;
    }

    .style2 {
        color: pink;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mandy8055 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting

Comment: @mandy8055 already supported by all the browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-nesting

Answer (score 1):

```
.service-page {

    & h1 {
        color: red;
    }

    .style1 {
        color: blue;
    }

    .style2 {
        color: pink;
    }
}
```

Use this. Hope it'll work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).